# Mysql Query for date-range

Tags: mysql, database

I have a booking table where all the service booking list where booking details saved like this:

```
 id   user_id   booking_date  booking_id
 1    3      2017-01-10        booking1
 2    3      2017-01-11        booking1
 3    3      2017-01-12        booking1
 4    3      2017-01-13        booking1
 5    3      2017-01-14        booking1
 6    4      2017-01-19        booking2
 7    4      2017-01-20        booking2
 8    4      2017-01-21        booking2
 9    4      2017-01-22        booking2
10    3      2017-02-14        booking3
11    3      2017-02-15        booking3
```

I want to get a start and end date of booking that came in a row. 
like for user_id 3 has 2 date range of booking date

```
from `2017-01-10 to 2017-01-14`
```

and then after some records

```
from `2017-02-14 to 2017-02-15`
```

Comment: Please provide the full desired result based on your sample.

Comment: shouldn't there be some booking id to define the entire range of a specific booking?

Comment: thank you all, yes there was booking_id i forgot to mention.. answer from MRonline worked from me

Comment: @shark, you check as solution a wrong answer. Does not match to your all requirements.

Comment: oh, i find it useful in a first sight.. let me verify it with my conditions ..

Comment: @danihp, it is perfectly working on my case .. thank you for taking your time to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think that getting sequences like that does make sense. ... But, ok.

To do this in one Query would be compicated with that data. So I would first add some column like "group_id" or "order_id". So you can save one ID to all orders that belong together.
Just iterate over the Table, ascending by ID and check if the next (or last) data has the same user_id.

When you do have the order_id column, you can simple

```
SELECT MIN(booking_date), MAX(booking_date) FROM table GROUP BY order_id
```

Comment: @shark, this query has some issues: `order_id` does not exists on your table and, more important, don't get 2 ranges for user_id 3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nobody says it is easy ... let's go. This is a gap and island problem. let me say it is mooooore easy to solve in postges sql

I apply mysql variables to your scenario.

I solve it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91075e/20):

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( user_id int,   booking_date date );
insert into t values 
 (    3,      '2017-01-10'),
 (    3,      '2017-01-11'),
 (    3,      '2017-01-12'),
 (    3,      '2017-01-13'),
 (    3,      '2017-01-14'),
 (    4,      '2017-01-19'),
 (    4,      '2017-01-20'),
 (    4,      '2017-01-21'),
 (    4,      '2017-01-22'),
 (    3,      '2017-02-14'),
 (    3,      '2017-02-15');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select user_id, min(booking_date), max(booking_date)
from (
 select t1.user_id, 
        t1.booking_date,
        @g := case when(
                      DATE_ADD(@previous_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <> t1.booking_date or
                      @previous_user <> t1.user_id ) 
                  then  t1.booking_date
                  else @g
            end as g,
        @previous_user:= t1.user_id,
        @previous_date:= t1.booking_date
 from t t1, ( select 
             @previous_user := -1,
             @previous_date := STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2000', '%m/%d/%Y'), 
             @g:=STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2000', '%m/%d/%Y') ) x
 order by user_id, booking_date
) X
group by user_id, g
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91075e/20/0)**:

```
| user_id | min(booking_date) | max(booking_date) |
|---------|-------------------|-------------------|
|       3 |        2017-01-10 |        2017-01-14 |
|       3 |        2017-02-14 |        2017-02-15 |
|       4 |        2017-01-19 |        2017-01-22 |
```

**Explanation** nested query figure up a `group code` ( `g` ) for each range. The external query get the max and the min for each group.

Comment: Though this is complicated i felt this is a nice way to do so, Thank you for your time :)